# Microsoft USD - Prevent user from Closing Session Tabs by clicking x button

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, hosted, unified-service-desk

Just like we can handle if the user can close a specific hosted control or not inside unified service desk like below,

[image]

Similarly, I want to know if there is anything similar to check we can prevent the user from closing the Session Tab or not. There is a **x** button right next to my session name so is there any out of the box way that we can prevent them from closing the session using that button?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom Panel Layout: https://carldesouza.com/creating-a-custom-layout-in-unified-service-desk/

You can edit the XAML that creates the tabs, sections, etc. behind the scenes. By doing this, you can delete the X button completely.

I would be careful against this - once a user opens a session, they will have no way to close it. Typically you define a session limit so that the user doesn't have too many things open at once. You will have to find an alternate way for the user to close the session.